# firefox stopping youtube video when expanding div

Tags: jquery, firefox, html

I am using jquery to expand a div with a youtube embed, but when I click to expand the div size *firefox* stops the youtube embed playing. *Chrome*, *IE9* etc do not stop the video playing when expanding the size. I am hoping someone will know of a solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wideView").click(function() {
        $("#youtube-movie").toggleClass("wide");
    });
});
```

Cheers

Comment: What solution do you want? One that stops the video in Chrome and IE9 or one that causes Firefox to keep playing?

Comment: Wait, so the video you're wanting to show is embedded inside of the DIV you're adding a click event too? Is that correct?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rVbQ6/ At least with FF8 and an `iframe`, it seems to work.

Comment: Having it work on the `DIV` also seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/rVbQ6/1/

Comment: What styling does the .wide class change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the code in your OP is the only thing that's happening then it's because
.wide dynamically changes `overflow` which causes a repaint of children elements in firefox. That means a flash player will reset and stop playing.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/rVbQ6/2/ (Do it in firefox and you will see)

The solution is to remove any overflow manipulations.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is why it's a *comment*. Abstract guessing is not an appropriate answer, as well.

Comment: Sorry guys. I was hoping for a solution for firefox.

Comment: @ShannonHyland, the solution for firefox is to remove the overflow manipulations from class `.wide`. I see that's just repeating myself though.

Comment: @ShannonHyland, can you link to the website where the problem is